# Intellisense for SQL dialects other than T-SQL

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

In Visual Studio 2013, is there a way to get intellisense working for SQL dialects/engines other than T-SQL (e.g. SQLite, MySQL, Potsgresql)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will be a RDBMS-by-RDBMS thing and may not be available for every RDBMS you want.

For MySQL, for example, check out [MySQL for Visual Studio 1.1.3 GA](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?3,603762,603762#msg-603762) ([download here](http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/windows/visualstudio/)), which apparently features IntelliSense.

For PostgreSQL, Devart [dotConnect for PostgreSQL](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/features.html) claims to offer IntelliSense.  (In contrast, Devart's overview of [dotConnect for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/) does not mention IntelliSense support; same with its overview of [dotConnect for SQLite](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/).)

Comment: For now I'll accept the "RDBMS-by-RDBMS" reality. Thank you.

Comment: Several years later, what's the current status?

Comment: Even MORE years later, I also came here wondering the same thing... I'd really like to be able to "accurately" look at SQL files for various other RDBMS systems in VS 2022 with at least a modicum of IntelliSense capability. As it stands, I have to disable the SQL IntelliSense entirely if I don't want to see a bunch of errors every time I open my `.sql` files.